Is $\int_s^t f(W_u)\mathrm{d}u$ independent to $\mathcal{F}_s$ for all (Lebesgue) measurable $f$?
I am trying to prove (or disprove) whether
$$
I[s,t]=\int_s^t f(W_u)\mathrm{d}u
$$
is independent of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_s$ for any $t,s$ with $t\geq s$, for $W=(W_t)_{t\geq 0}$ the standard Brownian motion. My intuition says it should, given that $W_t-W_s$ is independent to $\mathcal{F}_s$, and $f\mapsto f(W_t)$ does not add any information from the past into the model, yet I am having a hard time proving it rigorously or coming up with a counterexample.
Does anyone know whether this result actually holds true?

By integration-by-parts:
$$
\textstyle\int_s^tW_u\,du=tW_t-sW_s-\int_s^tu\,dW_u\,.
$$
The last integral is independent of ${\cal F}_s$ but the term $tW_t-sW_s$ is not.
It is of the form
$$
t(W_t-W_s)+(t-s)W_s
$$
of which only the increment $W_t-W_s$ is independent of ${\cal F}_s\,.$

Thank you very much for the answer! Would you mind looking at a slight reformulation of the problem in terms of stopping times here, I still believe that the sub-problem should have the independence property.

An old circus horse is usually reluctant to jump again as soon as the bar gets raised. I have read the beginning of the other post. Try to look at $\int_a^bf(W_s),ds$ and $\int_c^df(W_s),dW_s$ with non random times first.

I see that $\int_a^bu\mathrm{d}W_u$ is independent to $\mathcal{F}u$, but can we also say that for $\int_s^tu\mathrm{d}f(W_u)$? Writing our the integration by parts formula with the stopping times shows that $\int{\tau_0^n}^{\tau_0^{n+1}}f(W_u)\mathrm{d}u=-\int_{\tau_0^n}^{\tau_0^{n+1}}u\mathrm{d}f(W_u)$, but what can we say about the independence of the latter with $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_0^n}$?

With a general $f$ and non random times the ibp formula is $$\int_s^tf(W_u),du=tf(W_t)-sf(W_s)-\int_s^tu,df(W_u),.$$ For that reason I do not believe your identity involving stopping times. It should not be hard to conclude that the general $f$ won't make the integral independent of ${\cal F}_s,.$

This question is a bit unclear, should we show this for all possible $f$? A simple case where the independence is true is if $f$ is constant.
Otherwise, it is not true in general. I am assuming that $f(W_s)$ is integrable. If $I[s,t]$ was independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$, we would have $$\mathbb{E}[I(s,t) | \mathbb{F}_{s}] = \mathbb{E}[I(s,t)] = \int_{s}^{t} \mathbb{E}[f(W_u)]\ \mathrm{d}u. $$ However, since $W_{u} - W_{s}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$ and $W_s$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable, with $g(r,x) := \mathbb{E}[f(x + W_r)]$, what we actually have is
\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}[I(s,t) | \mathbb{F}_{s}] &= \int_{s}^{t}\mathbb{E}[f(W_u)| \mathbb{F}_{s}] \ \mathrm{d}u = \int_{s}^{t}\mathbb{E}[f(W_u - W_s + W_s)| \mathbb{F}_{s}] \ \mathrm{d}u \\ &= \int_{s}^{t} g(u-s, W_s) \ \mathrm{d}u, \end{align*}
which shows that $\mathbb{E}[I(s,t) | \mathbb{F}_{s}]$ depends on $W_s$ in general. As an example, if we let $f(x) = x^2$, we have
$$\int_{s}^{t} \mathbb{E}[W_u^2]\ \mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{2}(t^2-s^2),$$
while $g(r,x) = x^2 + r$ and therefore
$$ \int_{s}^{t} g(u-s, W_s) \ \mathrm{d}u = \int_{s}^{t} W_{s}^2 + (u -s) \mathrm{d}s = (t-s)W_{s}^2 + \frac{1}{2} (t-s)^2$$
